# Error building PyTorch on Nvidia Jetson Nano

Tags: docker, pytorch, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to build **PyTorch 1.11.0** in a Docker container running on a **Nvidia Jetson Nano**.

Towards the end of the compilation i get the following error:

```
[1668/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/UpSampleBilinear2d.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[1669/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/UpSampleLinear1d.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[1670/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/UpSampleNearest1d.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[1671/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/WeightNorm.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[1672/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/UnaryGeometricKernels.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[1673/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/UpSampleNearest2d.cu.o               
[1674/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ZetaKernel.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[1675/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/UpSampleNearest3d.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[1676/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/UpSampleTrilinear3d.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[1677/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScanKernels.cu.o                                
FAILED: caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScanKernels.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
/usr/bin/ccache /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -forward-unknown-to-host-compiler -DAT_PER_OPERATOR_HEADERS -DHAVE_MALLOC_USABLE_SIZE=1 -DHAVE_MMAP=1 -DHAVE_SHM_OPEN=1 -DHAVE_SHM_UNLINK=1 -DMINIZ_DISABLE_ZIP_READER_CRC32_CHECKS -DONNXIFI_ENABLE_EXT=1 -DONNX_ML=1 -DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx_torch -DTORCH_CUDA_BUILD_MAIN_LIB -DUSE_C10D_GLOO -DUSE_C10D_MPI -DUSE_CUDA -DUSE_DISTRIBUTED 
-DUSE_EXTERNAL_MZCRC -DUSE_RPC -DUSE_TENSORPIPE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Dtorch_cuda_EXPORTS -I/opt/pytorch/build/aten/src -I/opt/pytorch/aten/src -I/opt/pytorch/build -I/opt/pytorch -I/opt/pytorch/cmake/../third_party/cudnn_frontend/include -I/opt/pytorch/third_party/onnx -I/opt/pytorch/build/third_party/onnx -I/opt/pytorch/third_party/foxi -I/opt/pytorch/build/third_pa
rty/foxi -I/opt/pytorch/build/include -I/opt/pytorch/torch/csrc/distributed -I/opt/pytorch/aten/src/THC -I/opt/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/cuda -I/opt/pytorch/build/caffe2/aten/src -I/opt/pytorch/aten/../third_party/catch/single_include -I/opt/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/.. -I/opt/pytorch/c10/cuda/../.. -I/opt/pytorch/c10/.. -I/opt/pytorch/third_party/tensorpipe -I/opt/pytorch/buil
d/third_party/tensorpipe -I/opt/pytorch/third_party/tensorpipe/third_party/libnop/include -I/opt/pytorch/torch/csrc/api -I/opt/pytorch/torch/csrc/api/include -isystem /opt/pytorch/build/third_party/gloo -isystem /opt/pytorch/cmake/../third_party/gloo -isystem /opt/pytorch/third_party/protobuf/src -isystem /opt/pytorch/cmake/../third_party/eigen -isystem /usr/include/pyt
hon3.10 -isystem /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -isystem /opt/pytorch/cmake/../third_party/pybind11/include -isystem /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi -isystem /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libevent2022/libevent -isystem /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/openmpi/opal/mca/event/libe
vent2022/libevent/include -isystem /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include -isystem /opt/pytorch/cmake/../third_party/cub -isystem /usr/local/cuda-10.2/include -Xfatbin -compress-all -DONNX_NAMESPACE=onnx_torch -gencode arch=compute_53,code=sm_53 -gencode arch=compute_62,code=sm_62 -gencode arch=compute_72,code=sm_72 -Xcudafe --diag_suppress=cc_clobber_ignored,--diag
_suppress=integer_sign_change,--diag_suppress=useless_using_declaration,--diag_suppress=set_but_not_used,--diag_suppress=field_without_dll_interface,--diag_suppress=base_class_has_different_dll_interface,--diag_suppress=dll_interface_conflict_none_assumed,--diag_suppress=dll_interface_conflict_dllexport_assumed,--diag_suppress=implicit_return_from_non_void_function,--diag_suppress=unsigned_compare_with_zero,--diag_suppress=declared_but_not_referenced,--diag_suppress=bad_friend_decl --expt-relaxed-constexpr --expt-extended-lambda  -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets --expt-extended-lambda -DCUDA_HAS_FP16=1 -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__ -D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__ -D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__ -O3 -DNDEBUG -
std=c++14 -Xcompiler=-fPIC -DCAFFE2_USE_GLOO -D__NEON__ -DTH_HAVE_THREAD -Xcompiler=-Wall,-Wextra,-Wno-unused-parameter,-Wno-unused-variable,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-result,-Wno-unused-local-typedefs,-Wno-missing-field-initializers,-Wno-write-strings,-Wno-unknown-pragmas,-Wno-type-limits,-Wno-array-bounds,-Wno-unknown-pragmas,-Wno-sign-compare,-Wno-strict-overfl
ow,-Wno-strict-aliasing,-Wno-error=deprecated-declarations,-Wno-missing-braces,-Wno-range-loop-analysis,-Wno-maybe-uninitialized -DTORCH_CUDA_BUILD_MAIN_LIB -Xcompiler -pthread -MD -MT caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScanKernels.cu.o -MF caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScanKernels.cu.o.d -x cu -c /opt/pytorch/a
ten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScanKernels.cu -o caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/ScanKernels.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Killed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[1678/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/attention.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[1679/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/layer_norm_kernel.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[1680/1943] Building CUDA object caffe2/CMakeFiles/torch_cuda.dir/__/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/group_norm_kernel.cu.o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Building wheel torch-1.11.0a0+gitbc2c6ed                                                                                 
-- Building version 1.11.0a0+gitbc2c6ed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
cmake -GNinja -DBUILD_PYTHON=True -DBUILD_TEST=False -DCMAKE_BUILD=3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/pytorch/torch -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages -DCMAKE_VERSION=3.26 -DCUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -DNUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/b
in/python3.10 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.10 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so.1.0 -DTORCH_BUILD_VERSION=1.11.0a0+gitbc2c6ed -DUSE_CUDA=ON -DUSE_CUDNN=ON -DUSE_FAKELOWP=OFF -DUSE_FBGEMM=OFF -DUSE_MKLDNN=OFF -DUSE_NCCL=OFF -DUSE_NNPACK=OFF -DUSE_NUMPY=True -DUSE_OPENCV=OFF -DUSE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK=OFF -DUSE_QNNPACK=OFF -DUSE_SYSTEM_N
CCL=OFF -DUSE_XNNPACK=OFF /opt/pytorch                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
cmake --build . --target install --config Release -- -j 4                                                                                      
The command '/bin/sh -c export=BUILD_CAFFE2_OPS=OFF &&     export USE_FBGEMM=OFF &&     export USE_FAKELOWP=OFF &&     export BUILD_TEST=OFF &&     export USE_MKLDNN=OFF &&     export USE_NNPACK=OFF &&     export USE_XNNPACK=OFF &&     export USE_QNNPACK=OFF &&     export USE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK=OFF &&     export USE_CUDA=ON &&     export USE_CUDNN=ON &&     export TORCH_CU
DA_ARCH_LIST="5.3;6.2;7.2" &&     export USE_NCCL=OFF &&     export USE_SYSTEM_NCCL=OFF &&     export USE_OPENCV=OFF &&     export MAX_JOBS=4 &&     export PATH=/usr/lib/ccache:$PATH &&     export CC=clang &&     export CXX=clang++ &&     export CUDACXX=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc &&     python3.10 setup.py clean &&     python3.10 setup.py bdist_wheel' returned a non-zero
code: 1
```

My Dockerfile (my requirements are OpenCV 4.7.0, Python 3.10 and PyTorch 1.11.0), please consider that this Dockerfile is still in "debugging mode" and is far from optional.

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.7.1

ARG OPENCV_VERSION=4.7.0
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.11
ARG CMAKE_VERSION=3.26
ARG CMAKE_BUILD=3

# Setup ppa for python3.10
RUN set -ex && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt-get update

# Install build tools
RUN apt-get install -y \
    git \
    wget \
    build-essential \
    checkinstall \
    clang-8 \
    pkg-config \
    curl \
    unzip \
    wget \
    libtool \
    autoconf

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/clang-8 /usr/bin/clang && ln -s /usr/bin/clang++-8 /usr/bin/clang++
RUN apt remove -y --purge --auto-remove cmake


# Install cmake
RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev
WORKDIR /opt/
RUN wget https://cmake.org/files/v${CMAKE_VERSION}/cmake-${CMAKE_VERSION}.${CMAKE_BUILD}.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzvf cmake-${CMAKE_VERSION}.${CMAKE_BUILD}.tar.gz
WORKDIR cmake-${CMAKE_VERSION}.${CMAKE_BUILD}
RUN ./bootstrap
RUN make -j$(nproc)
RUN make install

# Install python3.10
RUN apt-get install -y python3.10 \
    python3.10-dev \
    python3.10-distutils \
    python3-pip \
    python3-numpy

RUN curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10 && \
    python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install numpy==1.22.4

################################
##  Build and install OpenCV  ##
################################
WORKDIR /opt/build

# Install OpenCV dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libtbb2 \
    libtbb-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libdc1394-22-dev \
    libeigen3-dev \
    libhdf5-100 libhdf5-dev \
    libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev \
    libprotobuf10 libprotobuf-dev \
    libjpeg8 libjpeg8-dev \
    libpng16-16 libpng-dev \
    libtiff5 libtiff-dev \
    libwebp6 libwebp-dev \
    libopenjp2-7 libopenjp2-7-dev \
    libtbb2 libtbb-dev \
    libeigen3-dev \
    tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-por libtesseract-dev \
    ffmpeg

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libgstreamer1.0* \
    ubuntu-restricted-extras \
    libgstreamer1.0-dev \
    libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev

RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip -O opencv.zip
RUN unzip opencv.zip -d /opt && rm -rf opencv.zip
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/${OPENCV_VERSION}.zip -O opencv_contrib.zip
RUN unzip opencv_contrib.zip -d /opt && rm -rf opencv_contrib.zip

RUN cmake \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/opencv_contrib-${OPENCV_VERSION}/modules \
    -D EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/eigen3 \
    -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3.10) \
    -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3.10 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
    -D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$(python3.10 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
    -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -D WITH_JPEG=ON \
    -D WITH_PNG=ON \
    -D WITH_TIFF=ON \
    -D WITH_WEBP=ON \
    -D WITH_JASPER=ON \
    -D WITH_EIGEN=ON \
    -D WITH_TBB=ON \
    -D WITH_LAPACK=ON \
    -D WITH_PROTOBUF=ON \
    -D WITH_V4L=ON \
    -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENCL=ON \
    -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
    -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
    -D WITH_GTK=OFF \
    -D WITH_QT=OFF \
    -D WITH_VTK=OFF \
    -D WITH_OPENEXR=OFF \
    -D WITH_OPENNI=OFF \
    -D WITH_XINE=OFF \
    -D WITH_GDAL=OFF \
    -D WITH_IPP=OFF \
    -D BUILD_OPENCV_PYTHON3=ON \
    -D BUILD_OPENCV_PYTHON2=OFF \
    -D BUILD_OPENCV_JAVA=OFF \
    -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_IPP_IW=OFF \
    -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF \
    -D BUILD_ITT=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_TESTS=OFF \
    /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION} >> cmake_out.txt 2>&1

RUN make -j$(nproc)
RUN make install
RUN rm -rf /opt/build/* && rm -rf /opt/opencv-${OPENCV_VERSION} && rm -rf /opt/opencv_contrib-${OPENCV_VERSION}

# #################################
# ##  Build and install PyTorch  ##
# #################################
RUN git clone -b v1.11.0 --depth=1 --recursive --recurse-submodules --shallow-submodules https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch.git /opt/pytorch
WORKDIR /opt/pytorch

RUN apt-get install -y \
    libomp5 \
    libopenmpi-dev \
    libomp-dev \
    ninja-build \
    ccache \
    gnupg2

RUN apt-get remove -y python3-numpy

RUN pip3 install -U setuptools && \
    pip3 install -U pip wheel mock pillow && \
    pip3 install -U scikit-build && \
    pip3 install -U cython Pillow numpy==1.22.4

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./pytorch-1.11-jetson.patch /opt/pytorch
RUN patch -p1 < pytorch-1.11-jetson.patch

RUN export=BUILD_CAFFE2_OPS=OFF && \
    export USE_FBGEMM=OFF && \
    export USE_FAKELOWP=OFF && \
    export BUILD_TEST=OFF && \
    export USE_MKLDNN=OFF && \
    export USE_NNPACK=OFF && \
    export USE_XNNPACK=OFF && \
    export USE_QNNPACK=OFF && \
    export USE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK=OFF && \
    export USE_CUDA=ON && \
    export USE_CUDNN=ON && \
    export TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="5.3;6.2;7.2" && \
    export USE_NCCL=OFF && \
    export USE_SYSTEM_NCCL=OFF && \
    export USE_OPENCV=OFF && \
    export MAX_JOBS=4 && \
    export PATH=/usr/lib/ccache:$PATH && \
    export CC=clang && \
    export CXX=clang++ && \
    export CUDACXX=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc && \
    python3.10 setup.py clean && \
    python3.10 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

The patch that I'm applying to the the files (i found this in multiple tutorials online).

```
diff --git a/aten/src/ATen/cpu/vec/vec256/vec256_float_neon.h b/aten/src/ATen/cpu/vec/vec256/vec256_float_neon.h
index 0327868..e484fba 100644
--- a/aten/src/ATen/cpu/vec/vec256/vec256_float_neon.h
+++ b/aten/src/ATen/cpu/vec/vec256/vec256_float_neon.h
@@ -26,6 +26,7 @@ inline namespace CPU_CAPABILITY {
 //    https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45824
 // Most likely we will do aarch32 support with inline asm.
 #if defined(__aarch64__)
+#if defined(__clang__) || (__GNUC__ > 8 || (__GNUC__ == 8 && __GNUC_MINOR__ > 3))
 
 #ifdef __BIG_ENDIAN__
 #error "Big endian is not supported."
@@ -715,5 +716,6 @@ Vectorized<float> inline fmadd(const Vectorized<float>& a, const Vectorized<floa
 }
 
 #endif /* defined(aarch64) */
+#endif /* defined(__clang__) */
 
 }}}
diff --git a/aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp b/aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp
index 1751128..a090e70 100644
--- a/aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp
+++ b/aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp
@@ -24,6 +24,7 @@ void initCUDAContextVectors() {
 void initDeviceProperty(DeviceIndex device_index) {
   cudaDeviceProp device_prop;
   AT_CUDA_CHECK(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&device_prop, device_index));
+  device_prop.maxThreadsPerBlock = device_prop.maxThreadsPerBlock / 2;
   device_properties[device_index] = device_prop;
 }
 
diff --git a/aten/src/ATen/cuda/detail/KernelUtils.h b/aten/src/ATen/cuda/detail/KernelUtils.h
index b36e78c..dea597f 100644
--- a/aten/src/ATen/cuda/detail/KernelUtils.h
+++ b/aten/src/ATen/cuda/detail/KernelUtils.h
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@ namespace at { namespace cuda { namespace detail {
 
 
 // Use 1024 threads per block, which requires cuda sm_2x or above
-constexpr int CUDA_NUM_THREADS = 1024;
+constexpr int CUDA_NUM_THREADS = 512;
 
 // CUDA: number of blocks for threads.
 inline int GET_BLOCKS(const int64_t N, const int64_t max_threads_per_block=CUDA_NUM_THREADS) {
```

On the Jetson Nano nvidia is set as the default docker runtime so that CUDA is available during docker build.